# Replace CodeMirror token?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm trying to replace a token selected in CodeMirror v3 via

```
var obj = editor.getTokenAt(currLine);
var currLine = editor.getCursor(true);
```

but it seems like the only options are to do

```
replaceRange
```

which takes the new string and the start position into consideration, but weird things happen when the new string is shorter or longer than the original.

What's a better way to do it?

```
currLinereplace
```

doesn't seem to work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: As an addendum, editor.replaceRange(newString, {line:currLine.line, ch:obj.start},{line:currLine.line, ch:obj.end}); works if newString is smaller or equal in size to the original string. Otherwise odd things happen.

Comment: This is very old question,but today I spent a lot of time to find out how to make it work and in case of custom hints and I've found a solution (I've posted an answer bellow): https://stackoverflow.com/a/63145524/4517057

Answer (score 4):

```
var pos = editor.getCursor() // or {line , ch };
var tok = editor.getTokenAt(pos);
editor.replaceRange("string", {line: pos.line , ch:tok.start},{line:pos.line , ch:tok.end});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to show **custom hint list** to replace join token on select.
Calling replaceRange method with correct parameters was **not enough**. It pasted new token, but inside of initial token depending on cursor position. If we have custom hint options we need to specify from and to positions **also in hint options** to make replaceRange work correctly e.g:

```
const options = {
    hint: () => ({
      from: token.start, // without this replaceRange didn't work not correctly
      to: token.end, // without this replaceRange didn't work not correctly
      list: ['left join', 'right join', 'inner join', 'outer join'] // custom list of options
    })
  };
  cm.showHint(options); // this is to show custom hint
```